# Replicating Identity column Query loads

Tags: query

I'm curious if any one has ever replicated the behavior of an Identity column in a query used to load a DE.  Essentially assigning a sequential number to each row as it is loaded into a DE.

Comment: You can add field of type Auto Number to any object which normally will create sequential numbers. (Gaps in the numbers can occur though.) Is this sufficient?

Comment: Appreciate the input on Auto Number.  Unfortunately, don' think it is available to use in my scenario, where I can only use standard interactions - no coding, no API usage allowed.